# Crystal report multi detail sections with different data ranks with C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need Crystal report similar to this one.*I don't know the technical term for this type of report.* I am new for the crystal report.

This solution for vehicle repair center.When repair vehicles they estimate the require items and faults.When giving the invoice I need to add what are the fault and what are the part to use for that vehicle.But fault by fault no need to describe parts.They want only fault list and part list separately.

***Header Part***

```
                                    Invoice
                                    -------
Customer Name : Brito Aden
Customer Code : 0010
Date          : 2015/8/1
```

***Details part 01***

```
Item No | Description | Qty
----------------------------

000001  Test 1      1       
000002  Test 1      1       
000003  Test 1      1       
000004  Test 1      1       
000005  Test 1      1       
000006  Test 1      1       
000007  Test 1      1
```

***Details part 02***

```
Faults List
-----------
1.Engine overheat.
2.Windscreen Damage.
3.Radiator leak.
4.Wheel alignment check.
```

***Document Footer***

```
Parts : 36
Items : 07


Total Price For parts : 2500 $
Total Price For Items : 7500 $
                       -------
Total                 :10000 $
                       =======
```

Comment: Do you want to drill into item 000001 to get details? Or are details part 01 and details part 02 unrelated?

Comment: details part 01 and details part 02 unrelated.But They add into same invoice

Comment: Try using sub reports as adviced by phil

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a pair of subreports. Each subreport can have its own query and formatting, but you can pass query parameters to the subreports via links. You can choose to "insert" the subreport from the menu. Then you place it, and start working with it.

Answer (score 0):

So its simple,  Just add all data of your database into ADO configuration,  if you want to override values that not are in your database, you cant do it.